# SharePoint files MD5 hash

Tags: sharepoint, md5

We have a client who requires that all image files within SharePoint are stored in a manner that it can be shown they are a bit for bit copy of the originally uploaded file. Obviously, hashing the file would be able to show that when the file is retrieved.

What I haven't been able to find it any reference to someone implementing this functionality on a SharePoint image library. I've found numerous articles around implementing this generically in C#, but ideally I'd like to be able to do it on a standard SharePoint document/image library.

Does anyone have any suggestions as how best to go about doing this? Workflow comes to mind, but what do people think? Also, as a side to this, does anyone know whether or not SharePoint will store a bit for bit copy that will verify when we compare the checksum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can to implement a [event handler](http://blogs.msdn.com/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx) which compute your file hash on upload and to store it in a metadata text field. It's a simple solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a Record Center site, they are designed for this sort of thing - verifiable archiving and storage.

Comment: The issue is we need to be able to prove that the files haven't been changed from their original state. It's for compliance in legal cases, so a hash seemed like the best way to demonstrate this. Record Center, while good with the auditing, etc, wouldn't tick all the boxes because of this. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would add a "text" column to the image library and then implement the hashing logic in an event receiver. You will need two handlers - ItemAdded and ItemUpdated. 
The code will look something like

```
    public override void ItemAdded(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        this.DisableEventFiring();
        properties.ListItem["myCustomField"] = this.CalculateHash(properties.ListItem.File);
        properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();
        this.EnableEventFiring();
   }
```